# How to run pytest in jenkins

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, pip, pytest

I am trying to run pytest in jenkins.
When i try to install pytest in build option in jenkins it says pip command not found. Even tried setting a virtual env but no success.

I AM RUNNING JENKINS IN DOCKER CONTAINER

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/bin
pip install pytest
py.test test_11.py
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source env1/bin/activate
pip install pytest
py.test test_11.py

Dockerfile

FROM Jenkins
USER root
```

Errors:

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
    Building on master in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pyproject
    [pyproject] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins5312265766264018610.sh
    /tmp/jenkins5312265766264018610.sh: line 4: pip: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
    Building on master in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pyproject
    [pyproject] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins6002566555689593419.sh
    /tmp/jenkins6002566555689593419.sh: line 4: pip: command not found
    /tmp/jenkins6002566555689593419.sh: line 5: py.test: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: please show your jenkins `Dockerfile`

Comment: @Ammar check it now

Answer (score 1):

well, the error is daylight clear, `pip` is not installed in the running environment.

I did some digging myself and found out that [jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) image has only `python2.7` installed, and `pip` is not installed.

I would start by installing `pip` first and continue from there, so modify `Dockerfile` to:

```
FROM jenkins
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

hope this helps you find your way.

*more helpful information could be:*

- your jenkins pipeline script (at least until step 'Execute shell')
- python version you intend to use.
- how and where you run the virtual-env creation command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I was trying to activate virtual environment in the build step in jenkins